# Querying for Facebook page statuses using PHP SDK 4 in cron

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've found a plenty of threads about this problem, but I haven't found any working solution.

All what I need to do is to download public page statuses in the background (using cron). I've used the following code so far.

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;

public function actionDownload() {
    $appId = "...";
    $appKey = "...";
    $pageId = '...';

    // Create FB session.
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appId, $appKey);
    $session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

    // Perform FB request.
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', "/" . $pageId . "/posts");
    $response = $request->execute();
    $results = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

    // Parse response and save results.
    /// ...
}
```

It works well with one exception. I don't want all posts. I need statuses only. So I've changed the "posts" edge to the "statuses" edge and now it fails with FacebookAuthorizationException (#100) Requires user session. It fails despite the "page/statuses" edge documentation states that

> Any valid access token is required to view any publicly shared statuses.

So what's wrong? And if app token is not sufficient, how can I get user access token in a background cron process?

Answer (score 0):

See the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed

Make sure the App Access Token is correct. Try to set the App Token on your own:

`$facebook->setAccessToken($appAccessToken);`

The App Access Token is just "App-ID|App-Secret".

With a correct Token it should work: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=bladauhu%2Fstatuses&version=v2.2

If you want User postings only, you may need to use the feed endpoint and filter out the Page postings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found this page [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/statuses) which states that there is a page/statuses endpoint which provides "the feed of status messages published by this page". So what is it good for?

Comment: must be an old page, not reachable through the page docs. "status messages published by this page" would be the /posts endpoint now.

Comment: oh, you´re right, it´s indeed still there on a separate page. weird.

Comment: Well, in fact, what I really need are page's posts physically written by the owner. Page/posts endpoint includes some extra items like stories about owner's comments on posts etc. This was the reason why I was trying to engage page/statuses endpoint. Is there any way to filter out those extra items from page/posts?

Comment: i think statuses may eben be correct then, or you could check the "status_type" flag in the response. i´ve updated my answer, check it out. make sure the app token is correct.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it didn't help. Even when I'm trying to post the same request in Graph API Explorer I have the same problem. {page-id}/posts with app access token works, but {page-id}/statuses with the same app access token fails with message (#100) Requires user session.